# How to pass session cookies from one tab to another in Headless Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I am using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to run headless chrome. Once I login I want to keep the session cookies for future use. Is there a way to save and load session cookies in puppeteer?

Looking for something like:

```
(async () => {
    console.log('start -> ', true);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(agent);
    await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 699});
    await page.goto('https://www.website.com/');

    await login(); // custom method for log in

    // here --->
    const sessionCookies = await page.cookies.toJSON();

    // and in another session --->
    await page.setCookies(cookiesJson);
})();
```

Comment: Have you seen the cookies api? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies and https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies.

Comment: I have tried the cookies api in 0.10.2 and it returned an empty array after login (login creates session cookies on regular chrome). Perhaps it only returns the cookies which were added manually and in 0.11.0 it was fixed. I did find this github issue thread which I am now following:https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/635

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`page.cookies()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls)

```
// here --->
const sessionCookies = await page.cookies();

// and in another session --->
await page.setCookies(sessionCookies);
```

Comment: It seems to be empty though after login there should be session cookies present. Perhaps it only shows the cookies you added manually... any idea?

Comment: @Joel You might be bitten by the same issue as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631516/368691.