# How to recreate a page with all of the cookies?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to:

1. Visit a page that initialises a session
2. Store the session in a JSON object
3. Visit the same page, which now should recognise the existing session

The implementation I have attempted is as follows:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const createSession = async (browser, startUrl) => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(startUrl);

  await page.waitForSelector('#submit');

  const cookies = await page.cookies();
  const url = await page.url();

  return {
    cookies,
    url
  };
};

const useSession = async (browser, session) => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  for (const cookie of session.cookies) {
    await page.setCookie(cookie);
  }

  await page.goto(session.url);
};

const run = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const session = await createSession(browser, 'http://foo.com/');

  // The session has been established
  await useSession(browser, session);
  await useSession(browser, session);
};

run();
```

1. `createSession` is used to capture the cookies of the loaded page.
2. `useSession` are expected to load the page using the existing cookies.

However, this does not work – the `session.url` page does not recognise the session. It appears that not all cookies are being captured this way.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that `page#cookies` returns some cookies with the `session=true,expires=0` configuration. `setCookie` ignores these values.

I worked around this by constructing a new cookies array overriding the `expires` and `session` properties.

```
const cookies = await page.cookies();

const sessionFreeCookies = cookies.map((cookie) => {
  return {
    ...cookie,
    expires: Date.now() / 1000 + 10 * 60,
    session: false
  };
});
```

At the time writing this answer, `session` property is not documented. Refer to the following issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/980.

Answer (score 3):

Puppeteer `page.cookies()` method only fetches cookies for the current page domain. However, there might be cases where it can have cookies from different domains as well.

You can call the internal method `Network.getAllCookies` to fetch cookies from all the domains.

```
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });

  // Here we can get all of the cookies
  console.log(await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies'));

})();
```

More on this thread here - [Puppeteer get 3rd party cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252943/puppeteer-get-3rd-party-cookies#)