# Puppeteer get 3rd-party cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

How can I get 3rd-party cookies from a website using Puppeteer?

For first party, I know I can use:

```
await page.cookies()
```

Comment: You probably can't. JS doesn't usually have that kind of access.

Comment: There must be some way. For example cookiepedia extract all cookies from any page

Comment: What makes you think cookiepedia is reading _your_ cookies?

Comment: Not my cookies. It just read page's cookies. Probably it open provided page and grab all cookies, 1st and 3rd party

Comment: What makes you think it's using JavaScript to do that?

Comment: It uses browser for sure, so you can use headless browser, and control it via for example puppeteer or something other

Comment: @PiotrWójcik Interesting — could you share a URL on Cookiepaedia where it reads your 3d-party cookies?

Comment: In fact I found 2 ways of doing it, and I can get all cookies. Now I need to refactor it, and find some spare time and I will provide solution here

Comment: @PiotrWójcik, would you share your research? I'm curious about the 2nd way you mentioned.

Comment: @Vaviloff F*k me I totally forgot about, sorry. Anyway, this code is gone for long time, but I found some parts of it, so it may be not complete:
1. Puppeteer creates in tested directory: ./Default/Cookies file which is simply sqlite database and all cookies are there.

Answer (score 33):

I was interested to know the answer so have found a solution too, it works for the current versions of Chromium 75.0.3765.0 and puppeteer 1.15.0 *(updated May 2nd 2019)*.

Using [internal puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/31) `page._client` methods we can make use of [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getAllCookies) directly:

```
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });

  // Here we can get all of the cookies
  console.log(await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies'));

})();
```

In the object returned there are cookies for google.com and imgur.com which we couldn't have obtained with normal browser javascript:

[image: 3d-party cookies!]

Comment: this no longer appears to work, as of Chrome 73.0.3683.103, right?

Comment: @noli I've installed latest puppeteer 1.15.0 with Chromium 75.0.3765 and it worked: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/GKQoj7b.png)

Comment: confirmed this works with puppeteer@1.17.0 and Chromium 74.0.3729.169

Comment: To anyone intereste: it still works for Chromium 92.0.4512.0 and puppeteer 10.0.0

Answer (score 12):

You can create a [Chrome DevTools Protocol session](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) on the [page target](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagetarget) using [`target.createCDPSession()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#targetcreatecdpsession). Then you can send [`Network.getAllCookies`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-getAllCookies) to obtain a list of all browser cookies.

The [`page.cookies()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls) function will only return cookies for the current URL. So we can filter out the current page cookies from all of the browser cookies to obtain a list of third-party cookies only.

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
const all_browser_cookies = (await client.send('Network.getAllCookies')).cookies;
const current_url_cookies = await page.cookies();
const third_party_cookies = all_browser_cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.domain !== current_url_cookies[0].domain);

console.log(all_browser_cookies); // All Browser Cookies
console.log(current_url_cookies); // Current URL Cookies
console.log(third_party_cookies); // Third-Party Cookies
```

Comment: Hello @Grant Miller - I was wondering how do we pass a specific web page to this, to acquire it's cookies for inspection?

Answer (score 1):

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.stackoverflow.com/', {waitUntil : 'networkidle0' });
  // networkidle2, domcontentloaded, load are the options for wai until
  // Here we can get all of the cookies
  var content = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(content, null, 4));
```

Comment: What does this add to the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290081/6243352)? This doesn't work on Pupp 19.1.0: `TypeError: page._client.send is not a function`