# Does puppeteer page.cookies() return all cookies?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Does puppeteer page.cookies() return all cookies including cross-domain ones ?

Comment: no, only for the current page URL. if you need all cookies here it was answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252943/puppeteer-get-3rd-party-cookies

Comment: Thx...just as a related question, for a regular web app running in Chrome, there is no way to get cross-domain cookies...Would that be correct ?

Comment: if I mean the same by cross-domain cookies like you (for me it is an interchangeable term with 3rd party cookies here) then, there is a way to get them with `await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies')`. you can compare its output with `page.cookies()`: this one will contain the 3rd party ones as well. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663733/12412595